# Cast MongoDB $objects ($oid, $date, $binary...) to Mongoose objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Well, I have used MongoDB in a while but I don't know how to handle this situation.

The scenario is: I have data inserted in MongoDB. I have exported the data in JSON format, and it is something like:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "60ff324f41c4d5b96054390d" },
    "field": {
      "due_date": { "$date": "2021-11-03T00:09:18.271Z" }
    }
  }
]
```

You can see that :

- `_id` is `{ "$oid": "60ff324f41c4d5b96054390d" }` and
- `date` is `{ "$date": "2021-11-03T00:09:18.271Z" }`.

So, the problem is trying to insert in another DB using Mongoose. I want to test some funcionality isolated so I wan't these values in other environment, so I have used `insertMany()` with the JSON previously exported.

(Maybe there is a more elegant way to import a JSON file but is only for testing purposes)

```js
await model.insertMany(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data.json').toString()))
```

But the problem is here: It throws an error because my schema says that `_id` is an `ObjectId` and `due_date` is a `Date` object but they are actually read as objects: `{$oid: ""}` and `{$date: ""}`

```
ValidationError: model validation failed: _id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ '$oid': '60ff324f41c4d5b96054390d' }" (type Object) at path "_id", field.due_date: Cast to date failed for value "{ '$date': '2021-11-03T00:09:18.271Z' }" (type Object) at path "field.due_date"
```

So the question is: Is there any way to cast the `$oid` and `$date` objects using mongoose while inserting?

Also, I have managed to insert the values using a very ugly script iterating over each value and checking if the object is `$oid` or `$date` and modifying the values... but it works.

So the question is not: "Is there a workaround to do this?" but "Is there a way to do it directly with mongoose functions as `insertMany` and casted automatically?"

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share that script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{"$oid": ...}` and `{"$date":...}` constructs are MongoDB extended JSON notation, since JSON does not have any type for `Date` or `ObjectId`.

In order to insert those values, you will need to use a JSON parser that knows about this extended format.

One possibility is the `json_util` that is included with `bson`.

Or you can use [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/#mongoimport) to read the JSON file and do the inserts for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is `json_util` available for JS? I only found docs for python. Also I'll take a look to execute `mongoimport` from JS code because I'm using a DB in memory. But it seems is not possible to do it directly using Mongoose, right?

Comment: Ah, right, for Node.js it is called EJSON, and is included with the BSON npm package: https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson#ejson